# flink data is not processed by the process function in a timewindow operator

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a timewindow that I try to determine if I get a new key over a period of time. I am pushing data via kafka and when I debug it, I see that the data is getting to the `keyby` method but it is not reaching the `process` method and not being collected by the collector. I am using `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` for assigning watermarks :

```
    case class Src(qip:Ip, ref: Ip, ts: Long) extends FooRequest

    class TsExtractor extends BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Src](Time.hours(3)){
      override def extractTimestamp(element: Src): Long = element.ts
    }

    class RefFilter extends ProcessWindowFunction[Src, IpDetectionSrc, String, TimeWindow]{
      private lazy val stateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor("refFilter",  createTypeInformation[String])

      override def process(key: String, context: Context, elements: Iterable[Src], out: Collector[IpDetectionSrc]): Unit = {
        println(s"RefIpFilter processing $key")//data is not getting here 
        if(Option(context.windowState.getState(stateDescriptor).value()).isEmpty){
          println(s"new key found $key") //data is not getting here also 
          context.windowState.getState(stateDescriptor).update(key)
          out.collect(elements.head)
        }
      }
    }

lazy val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment =
    setupEnv(StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment)(300000,Some(stateDir), Some(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime))

 lazy val src: DataStream[FooRequest] = env.addSource(consumer)

 lazy val uniqueRef:DataStream[FooRequest] => DataStream[Src] = src => src 
        .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction[FooRequest,Src ]{
          override def flatMap(value: FooRequest, out: Collector[Src]): Unit =   value match {
            case r: Src =>
              out.collect(r)
            case invalid =>
              log.warn(s"filtered unexpected request $invalid")
          }
        })
        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TsExtractor)
        .keyBy(r => r.ref)
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(120))
        .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(360))
        .process(new RefFilter)

uniqueRef(src).addSink(sink)
env.execute()
```

any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How long are you waiting? You'd need to wait at least 2 min + 6 min until the first RefFilter is triggered.

Comment: How are you testing this? You will have to push through an event that's roughly 3 hours + 2 mins later than the earliest event before generating a watermark that can trigger the first window.

Comment: Also, note that `context.windowState.getState(stateDescriptor).value()` will always be empty, unless there are late events. Six minutes of allowed lateness compared to watermarks that are already delayed by 3 hours suggests there won't be very many late events.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, I was actually testing a single event. why would the `context.windowState.getState(stateDescriptor).value()` remain empty if there are no late events ? In production I do have late events up to 3hrs. but how can I test a single event ? what do you recommend that I should change ?

Comment: If you want to test stuff, I recommend to make the time values configurable and set them to much lower values during testing.

Comment: thanks @ArvidHeise but i am not sure that i following you. can you set an example or something ?

Comment: Instead of using `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Src](Time.hours(3))`, use `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor[Src](watermarkDelay)` where `watermarkDelay` is passed as a parameter to your script or whatever builds the topology. Same with windowTime and allowedLateness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` keeps track of the highest timestamp it has seen so far, and produces watermarks that trail behind this by the configured delay (so three hours, in this case). These watermarks are produced periodically, every 200 msec by default. So with only a single event, the watermark will be 3 hours behind this event, and the window will never be triggered. Furthermore, with finite input, the job will stop running once it has processed all of the events.

`context.windowState` is per-window state, with a limited lifetime. Each 2 minute window will have its own instance, and it is cleared once the allowed lateness for the window has expired. If you want keyed window state with a global scope, with an indefinite lifetime, use `context.globalState` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to verify that the same key didn't arrived in a limited time frame in this case 2 minutes (in production we use hours ) , so I need to set the `allowedLateness` and the `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` to be the same ?